# Prove $\vec i^i = \vec i_i$ in rectangular coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vectors

Prove $\vec i^i = \vec i_i$ where $\vec i_i$ is a basis vector and $\vec i^i$ is a dual basis vector in rectangular cartesian coordinates.

My attempt:

$\vec i^i \cdot \vec i_j = \delta_j^i$
$\delta_j^i = 1$ if $i=j$
$\vec i^i \cdot \vec i_i = 1$

Since the bases in rectangular coordinate systems are orthonormal...

$\vec i_i = 1$

Given that $\vec i^i \cdot \vec i_i = 1$...

$\vec i_i = \vec i^i = 1$

Thanks!

Comment: Letter $i$ to denote tensor, letter $i$ to denote index... now all you need is the letter $i$ to denote the complex scalar and you'll have a truly unholy trinity.

Comment: Haha yes, the notation is pretty redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this from a geometric perspective, but there may be a more general way to see it!

You see, Euclidean space is actually a Riemannian space with $g=I$ or $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ in Cartesian coordinates. 
What you seem to be asking is about the [musical isomorphism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism) and [raising and lowering indices](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_and_lowering_indices). Here we are talking about vectors and covectors, but more generally one can talk about contravariant and covariant tensors. In any case, when a metric is available, one can lower an index by contracting with the metric.

So, in this case: $$ v_j = g_{ij}{v}^i = \delta_{ij}v^i $$
where notice that the RHS is just the $j$th component of the vector.

Or, in matrix-vector notation: $$ v = Iu = u $$ where $v$ is the dual of $u$.

See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/865079/are-vectors-and-covectors-the-same-thing) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50222/covectors-and-vectors).